# Return key/value pairs from dict if values are found in list

Tags: python

I have a list with several Active Directory codes. I also have a dictionary that is built from a live query of the AD, meaning this dictionary does not hold constant key/value pairs. I get a large number of AD events each time the server is queried, but I'm only interested in some of them. AD events are categorized by event IDs, which contain a brief description of what they are.

My dictionary contains both the description and the ID, and my list contains only the codes I'm interested in.

```
event_code_list = ['4662','4738','4763','4733','4730','4737','4753','4670','4754','4750']

events_and_ids = {'logged-in': '4624', 
                 'Directory Service Access': '4662', 
                 'permissions-changed': '4670', 
                 'created-process': '4688', 
                 'logged-out': '4634', 
                 'exited-process': '4689', 
                 'user-member-enumerated': '4799',
                 'Directory Service Access': '4662'}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to see which dict values match the IDs in the list, or vice-versa, and then return a dictionary with the matching key/value pairs.

```
{'Directory Service Access': '4662','permissions-changed': '4670'}
```

All my attempts have so far failed. The sampel below returns all key/value pairs in the dictionary regardless if the value is matches or not, which is obviously wrong.

```
for e in event_code_list:
    if e in events_and_ids.values() and e in event_code_list:
        print(events_and_ids.items())
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're new to Python. Here's a couple of examples that both do the same thing:

```py
filtered = {k: v for k, v in events_and_ids.items() if v in event_code_list}
```

```py
filtered = {}
for k, v in events_and_ids.items():
    if v in event_code_list:
        filtered[k] = v
```

list/dict comprehension breakdown, by request:

```py
# this is the same exact dict comprehension code, just with newlines and comments added
filtered = {
    k: v                                # syntax to define dict
    for k, v in events_and_ids.items()  # same as loop-based example
    if v in event_code_list             # same as loop-based example
}
```

If the dict and list are particularly long (say, if their lengths multiplied together can be over 10k~100k), then covert the `list` into a `set` first:

```py
events_to_keep = set(event_code_list)
filtered = {k: v for k, v in events_and_ids.items() if v in events_to_keep}
```

Comment: Great answers. Could you expand on the list comprehension?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the thorough examples!